# Validating many input fields on a form before SUBMIT

Tags: javascript, validation, dom-events

I  have a form having a table containing many input boxes that will be filled with data from database, that the user will edit.

Upon saving, I want all the input boxes to be validated to check whether user has entered a valid data such as 'numeric value only' or the box is not empty?

Is there any easy/optimised way to check all the boxes before the submission?

Comment: Can you "JQuery" ? http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation.

Comment: i did google, but could get any optimized solution..

Comment: dnt have much idea about JQuery.. just tell the logic.. I will go by javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a [simple javascript validator from javascript-coder.com](http://www.javascript-coder.com/html-form/javascript-form-validation.phtml), that lets you set rules.

It has a turtorial on how to set up.

And [10 Useful jQuery Form Validation Techniques and Tutorials](http://speckyboy.com/2009/12/17/10-useful-jquery-form-validation-techniques-and-tutorials-2/)  has examples on how to do this in jquery.

Comment: this is nice.. i will try it.. but the main problem is there are too many input boxes to validate.